# GenericUDAFResolver2 is deprecated, how should we implement UDAF now?

Tags: java, hive

As shown at the [deprecated-list for hive 3.0.0](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r3.0.0/api/deprecated-list.html), GenericUDAFResolver2 is now marked as deprecated. How should one implement a customized UDF? The [built-in UDAFs](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDAFCount.java) are still using `GenericUDAFResolver2` as well, what's going on?

Comment: The javadoc for `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFResolver2` says it's deprecated. But doesn't provide an alternate!

Comment: Here's a bug asking for the issue to be fixed: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-25694